# Linux: Traverse Server Directory and build List of Checksums for all Files

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, checksum

I am running a web server with several CMS sites.

To be aware of hacks on my web server, I am looking for a mechanism, by the help of which I can detect changed files in my web server.

I think of a tool / script, which traverses the directory structure, builds a Checksums for each file and writes out a list of files, with file size, last modified date and checksums.

At the next execution, I would then be able to compare this list with the previous one and detect new or modified files.

Dies anyone know a script or tool, which can accomplish this?

Comment: http://www.la-samhna.de/library/scanners.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check that.